# How to add OnClickListener to image button in the ListView Header in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have added a custom header to the ListView in android. The layout xml file for Header contains an Image button. How can I add an OnClickListener to this ImageButton

Header Layout File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#336699">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/add" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Code for binding the ListView (I have created a custom Adapter)

```
 ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    LocationAdapter adapter = new LocationAdapter(this,R.layout.listrow,webresult);
    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listheader, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question.

Comment: `header.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { /* ... */ }});`

Comment: But it's not recommended. ListViews shouldn't have onClickListeners but onItemClickListeners. Just saying;)

Answer (score 1):

When you add a header to listview it's considered the element `0` of your list. So you don't add an `onClickListener` but do it as you'd do with a regular row in a list:

```
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          if(position==0) //do your stuff
        }
    });
```