# Android: button in header view

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-button, togglebutton

I have a list view with a header. I want to have a clickable ToggleButton in the header. The button shows up okay, but I can't seem to make it clickable. Is there something special you have to do to make a listview header ToggleButton clickable?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "clickable"?  Do you mean, the button isn't changing color when you touch it, or you just aren't getting the event when the button is clicked?

I'm guessing you just didn't set up an OnClickListener?  You need to set up an OnClickListener either in your XML file, or in your Java file where you're setting up the view.

[Here's the answer to a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084855/how-to-add-onclicklistener-to-image-button-in-the-listview-header-in-android)

Comment: I mean it doesn't change color when you click it. I have checked that the clicks are being received by the onCheckedChangeListener, but the appearance of the button isn't changing as I have specified in my selector.

Comment: I have other buttons using the list itself using the same selector, and they work fine.